# nHibernate - split query result by child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

I've got two classes(actually more ones):

```
public class City{
  public string Name;
  public List<Street> Street;
}
public class Street{
  public string Name;
  public City City;
}
```

I'm trying to retreive filtered data using ICriterion approximately like this:

```
ICriteria crit = CurrentSession
                .CreateCriteria(typeof (City));
crit = crit.CreateAlias("Streets", "Street", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Name", "London", MatchMode.Exact));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Street.Name", "Pic%", MatchMode.Exact));
```

How should I form the criteria to get the result as the list of City containing child collection of Street with exactly one element? 
So I need to get the next result:

```
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Piccadilly'}
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Pickard'}
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Pickwick'}
```

etc.
but at the moment I'm getting:

```
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Piccadilly', 'Pickard', 'Pickwick'}
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Piccadilly', 'Pickard', 'Pickwick'}
City: 'London' -> Streets:{'Piccadilly', 'Pickard', 'Pickwick'}
```

Number of rows = Number of found streets. I need something like 'ungrouping by Streets across all rows'

Answer (score 0):

i would discourage the use of City as resultset because it won't be a valid city objects.

```
ICriteria crit = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(City))
    .CreateAlias("Streets", "Street", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Name", "London", MatchMode.Exact))
    .Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Street.Name", "Pic%", MatchMode.Exact))
    .SetProjection(Projections.List()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Name"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("Street.Name")));


var results1 = crit.List<object[]>()
    .Select(arr => new LocationDto
                   {
                       CityName = (string)arr[0],
                       StreetName = (string)arr[1]
                   });

// or if it is really needed
var results2 = crit.List<object[]>()
    .Select(arr => new City
                   {
                       Name = (string)arr[0],
                       Streets = { new Street((string)arr[1]) }
                   });
```